# encoding character in sqlite android

Tags: java, android

Hello i am reading english and afrikaans language from two different file and put into one sqlite database the word is correct in afrikaans language for example

the afrikaans word is below

```
    'n slegte lot
     'n voël die wilde diere van die prooi
      'n trekvogel
```

==========================================================

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DbAdapterSDCard db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String array[] = { "afrikaans" };
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        String filePath1 = "/sdcard/Dictionarys/english.txt";
        String filePath2 = "/sdcard/Dictionarys/" + array[j] + ".txt";
        String UTF8 = "utf8";
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(array[j]);
        db = new DbAdapterSDCard(array[j]);
        try {
            db.open();
            File file = new File(filePath3);
            file.createNewFile();

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(filePath1),UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);

            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(filePath2), UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);

            String sCurrentLine1, sCurrentLine2;

            while ((sCurrentLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null
                    && ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null)) {
                db.insertTitle(sCurrentLine1, sCurrentLine2);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

## }

but in sqlite it is inserted like this way
[image]

both have encoding UTF-8 Character set...........

can anybody suggest me i have tried so much but could not be success

encoding in txt file is below

[image]

now if i use encoding utf-8 the character will not shown proper :(

[image]

Comment: use String Replace methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:
First you have to clean your application because every build you make in your apk, you recreate database and sometimes changing encoding in your code won't show give you effects.

First you have to clean your application by redirecting to your package name using adb i.e

> ~/android-sdks/platform-tools/./adb shell pm clear com.example.my.project

or if you are in android sdk platform tools folder

> adb shell pm clear com.example.my.project

and then

> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:com.example.my.project

Please use this command every time when you are going to make changes with your databse. I made few changes and I didn't see any effects until I used adb command.

Second put encoding charset while reading lines from i.e file (linux example):

```
private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        //DATABASE_NAME is just a name of database

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(COMMAND_CREATE_TABLE);
        //COMMAND_CREATE is just command to create table i.e.
        //CREATE TABLE myTable ( _id int...

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_base_file);
            BufferedReader bufferReader;

            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, ENCODING));

                String line = "";

                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    db.execSQL(COMMAND_INSERT_START + line + COMMAND_INSERT_END);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Cursor fetchAllRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = this.sqlDatabase;
    return localSQLiteDatabase.query("myTable", ROWS_COLUMNS_NAME, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

It would be nice to convert your file with data to i.e UTF-8 before all operations.
Here is a sample code how to do this (linux version):

> iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t UTF-8 -o convertedBase.csv originalBase.csv

If you are windows user you can try use notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Android sqlite uses UTF-8 by default. So it looks like the problem is when you read from your files.

Try adding encoding to InputStreamReader

```
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(filePath2), "utf-8"), BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Or you can dig in the db.open() function.

Comment: I have used also like this way but same encoding exits

Comment: There is a file encoding as well, how do you generate the file?  Try open the files in a editor that can figure out the file encoding. I used Notepad++  for this.

Comment: Look i am posting picture of that

Comment: `new OutputStreamWriter(file3, "UTF-8");` too.

Comment: but Joop Eggen i am not using outputStream i am just inserting value into database

Comment: hai Danial Look at tht picture in tht encoding is ascii i have take screen shot and i m also using notepad++ that's good point to understand u

Comment: Ah, just convert it to utf-8 then upload to your android device. And run your code with InputStreamReader with encoding "utf-8"

Comment: Daniel if i tried with UTF-8 the character in notepad++ will not shown proper

Comment: Create a new text file,  make sure its in utf-8 encoding,  add some text which have special chars (ë) ,  should be shown properly.

Comment: ok let's me try otherwise look i have upload new picture also

Comment: Hello Daniel i have done first save file with UTF-8 and then all words i have done copy paste and then done read write operation but still in database same value are comming have u tried anywhere????

Comment: Is the special chars(ë) correct in the utf8 text file?    should not be "xEB",  replace these manually then save upload, run program.

Comment: Daniel thank you so much for giving me ur valuable time i can not upvote ur answer 5 times otherwise i will do it

Comment: Look danial if i first save file with utf 8 and then copy paste all the character it will look fine no any xEB character will be shown

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25083/discussion-between-siddhpura-amit-and-daniel-magnusson)